# Define a string with parts coming from other defines(non strings)

Tags: c++, string, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to create a version string, which is treated as a char* when used.
I'm currently using

```
#define VERSION_MAJOR @cmakeproject_VERSION_MAJOR@
#define VERSION_MINOR @cmakeproject_VERSION_MINOR@
#define VERSION_PATCH @cmakeproject_VERSION_PATCH@
#define VERSION_STRING "" VERSION_MAJOR "." VERSION_MINOR "." VERSION_PATCH
```

After cmake configures, this will look like

```
#define VERSION_MAJOR 1
#define VERSION_MINOR 2
#define VERSION_PATCH 3
#define VERSION_STRING "" VERSION_MAJOR "." VERSION_MINOR "." VERSION_PATCH
```

As far as I understand, VERSION_STRING at compile-time will end up looking like

```
"" 1 "." 2 "." 3
```

And, this results in error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant

Is there a way to make it so that VERSION_STRING at compile time looks like "1.2.3"?

Comment: What is "@cmakeproject_VERSION_MAJOR@"? Is that some kind of define?

Comment: Shouldn't your `#define`'s look like `#cmakedefine`? This looks like a `SomeHeader.h.in` that cmake would use to generate a real `SomeHeader.h` based on configuration parameters. If that's the case, cmake will change `#cmakedefine ... @...@` to `#define ... VALUE`

Comment: this file is named project.h.in, it is processed at configure time by cmake, which results in a file that looks like 

`#define VERSION_MAJOR 0`
`#define VERSION_MINOR 0`
`#define VERSION_PATCH 0`
The fact that cmake is involved should not be change anything, as they will just be integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stringification with slingshot should do the trick:

```
#define QU(x) #x
#define QUH(x) QU(x)
#define VERSION_STRING QUH(VERSION_MAJOR) "." QUH(VERSION_MINOR) "." QUH(VERSION_PATCH)
```

It'll expand to `"1" "." "2" "." "3"`, which is the same as `"1.2.3"`.

Comment: @Levi: Sorry, I forgot that you need to slingshot the macros through a helper. Edited!

Comment: Well, it created an interesting effect, it resulted in `VERSION_STRING` being defined as `"VERSION_MAJOR.VERSION_MINOR.VERSION_PATCH"`

Comment: @Levi: Are you sure you've defined the `VERSION_MAJOR` etc. macros before you defined `VERSION_STRING`?

Comment: Yes, I'm not pasting before, your lines are immediately after the three lines that define the `VERSION_(MAJOR/MINOR/PATCH)`

Comment: @Levi: yes yes yes, I forgot, it's coming back now -- you need to double-slingshot it with a helper. Now it works, I tested it! Sorry for this shoddy presentation.

Comment: Thanks! That seems a bit silly that it would need that, but Thanks so much! I'll keep this in mind for later 'define-ish to string'

Comment: @Levi: This is a fairly well known construction (all the more embarrassing that it took me three attempts), and I don't think it can be done any more directly: You need one substitution to get your macro replaced by its value, and another one to get the value stringified...